# what does the "p" in "pselect" and "ppoll" meaning?

Tags: linux, systems-programming

I haven read the man pages, but I still can't get the figure the prefix "p" in "pselect", and also "ppoll". 
So what is the "p" stand for in theses function?

Comment: I think it stands for POSIX.

Comment: thank you Barmar! It sounds reasonabe! I was always try to link this "p" to something like "sigmask"  or something about "struct timespec" or even "re-entrant"... ...                 By the way, do you know the libuv that Node.js use? what does that "uv" in "libuv" mean?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with it, but the documentation says that libuv replaced libev, so I suspect they just modified the name a little. "ev" presumably stood for "event".

Comment: You can't always expect names to be perfectly meaningful.

Comment: Yes, I know that doc, and read that connection with libev, and 'ev' in the libev is straightforward. But that 'uv' is obscure, the 'v' maybe still meaning 'event', but the 'u' in 'uv' is hard to guess. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: It probably doesn't mean anything. Like I said, they just needed to replace `e` with something else. Maybe it means "universal", since a big difference was that it was ported to Windows while libev was Unix-only.

Comment: yes! that's make sense !